# GetPropertiesAsync on BlobBaseClient does not return from the server

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a seekable blob read stream for reading zip entry from my blob storage
and for that I want to know what is the length of the  content, and for that I need to call

```
BlobContainerClient client = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("my-container");    
BlobProperties properties = client.GetProperties() 
long Length = properties.ContentLength;
```

At the initialization of the my seekable blob stream but the get properties is stuck and not returning back from the client

I tried this too

```
BlobContainerClient client = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("my-container");    
BlobProperties properties = client.GetPropertiesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value; 
long Length = properties.ContentLength;
```

The Nugets that I used there:

1. Azure.Storage.Blobs Version="12.10.0"
2. Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage Version="23.0.0"

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem as you, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the **client** in your `client.GetProperties()`. But you can get the length of the blob's content with the [`BlobProperties.ContentLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobproperties.contentlength?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobProperties_ContentLength), as shown below example.

```cs
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("connectionString");
BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient("blobName");
var properties = blob.GetProperties();
Console.WriteLine(properties.Value.ContentLength);
```

Instead of printing the length as shown in the above example you can store it.

Comment: Hi thanks ,I'm sorry about that mistake but I meant that the client is the container, now I fixed the naming issue. and it's the same as you wrote but the GetProperties function is stuck

Comment: Could you try to get properties of blob instead of the container as I have shown in the example **blob.GetProperties()** and check if the connection string is correct.

Comment: Yes I tried, and it's stuck.

Comment: I did one more test and I called BlobItem blob = container.GetBlobs().FirstOrDefault().Properties; and it's work but when I try to work with BlobClient it's stuck